# Why are the decimal points being ignored?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

So I am working on this little compound interest calculator and I'm having a problem that I don't know how to fix!
For some reason python appears to not care about the fact that there are decimals in the numbers. For example if a number is 12588.01 in the code it is treated like 12588.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
p = 12588.01  #principle
r = 4.9  #rate as percent
t = 20  #time

# math
r = r / 100

# math and output
for i in range(t):
    interest = p * r
    #interest = round(interest, 2)

    #generates the spaces between the time and numbers
    timeSpace = 5 - len(str(i+1))
    timeSpace = " " * int(timeSpace)

    #generates the spaces used in the first part of the output
    firstSpace = 10 - len(str(round(p)))
    firstSpace = " " * int(firstSpace)

    #generated the space used in the second part of the output
    secondSpace = 10 - len(str(round(interest)))
    secondSpace = " " * int(secondSpace)

    #output

    #print("Year: %d%s|%d%s|%d%s|%d" % (i+1, timeSpace, round(p, 2), firstSpace, interest, secondSpace, round(interest+p, 2)))
    print("Year: %d%s|%d%s|%d%s|%d" % (i+1, timeSpace, float(p), firstSpace, float(interest), secondSpace, float(interest+p)))

    p = p + interest
    #p = round(p, 2)
```

This calculator is working with currency and should round because of that, however during my attempts to fix the code, I commented them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the float with `%d`, which is for integers. Use `%.2f` to print a float to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Use string formating with the correct formats:

```
p = 12588.01  #principle
r = 4.9  #rate as percent
t = 20  #time

r /= 100

for i in range(t):
    interest = p * r
    print(f"Year: {i+1:<5d}|{p:<10.2f}|{interest:<10.2f}|{interest+p:.2f}")
    p += interest
```